# How is "first-name" a reserved word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object-literal, reserved-words

*Note: This question pertains to the book 'JavaScript: The Good Parts' written by Doug Crockford.*
As I was reading a chapter on Objects, I came across a statement as follows:

> The quotes around a property's name in an object literal are optional if the name would be a legal JavaScript name and not a reserved word. So quotes are required around **`"first-name"`**, but are optional around **`"first_name"`**.

And the following is the example of an object literal provided in the book:

```
var stooge = {
    "first-name": "Jerome",
    "last-name": "Howard"
};
```

Now, I might have misinterpreted the text here but to me it seems like Mr. Crockford is saying   **`first-name`** (with the hyphen) IS a reserved word whereas **`first_name`** (with the underscore) is not. If that is the case, I don't understand how the former can be a reserved word. I found no other explanation in the book why this is. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a reserved word. Without the quotes, javascript will interpret the `-` character as a subtraction operator, attempt to perform the operation, and fail.

One reason for this is that javascript prefers to ignore whitespace whenever it can. Thus `2 - 3` is the same as `2-3`.

Putting the whole thing in quotes causes the js to interpret as just another character, not an operator.

Comment: Jeffman, it makes perfect sense. It didn't occur to me first how the hyphen can be interpreted as such!